# Take renders of every combination of objects in collections?

Tags: rendering, scripting

I am pretty new to blender, and have a simple scene setup to render objects, I typically use F12, then scrape that screenshot with snippit, kludgy but simple
Now what I'm looking to do, is have a few collections, and take every combination of one object from each collection, and render them

so collection 1, 2, 3 have objects a b and c in them, i'd need render 1a_2a_3a , 1a_2a_3b and so on

My first thought is I need a script of some flavor, but with some intense googling I have only been able to find people trying to take renders of the same objects, but with different colors or textures

any thoughts/help? =/

Comment: Do all the collections have all the objects in them (each object is in three collections)?

Comment: @TheLabCat Yeah, each collection has its own group of individual objects, no object exists in more than one collection, I could rename them however we want so the script or whatever knows what to toggle, if I have to rename everything with a convention "group1_A" "group1_C" whatever, thats fine, I can change the environment to match whatever we can come up with. there's obviously another collection with the light sources and backdrop and such which should remain on.

Really, there aren't that many objects (only 4-8 in each group, but up to like 8 or 10 groups)

Comment: So… I’m guessing this is going to be a combination lock or something. But no matter, this can be scripted. The API can pretty easily hide and show objects, and I think it can call a render too. The tricky part would be running through every combination. What you need is a numerical base counter…

Comment: To be honest I could program something like this in VBA, but this is all new to me, just calling out 8 or 10 variables, and the including the variable in the object name so they can be cycled on and off seem to be doable, then loops within loops for each one.

I'll do some more poking around to see if I can figure out how this scripting works and some functions

Comment: good luck (non sarcastic). It is in Python, so it should be pretty easy. GHY.

Comment: I’ll look into it later when I get a chance

Comment: Thanks, I know absolutely nothing about python, so this will be a whole adventure ~.~